# what is the difference between two downloadable versions of giraph: 1.2giraph-dist-1.2.0-hadoop2-bin.tar.gz and giraph-dist-1.2.0-bin.tar.gz

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, giraph

What is the difference between
giraph-dist-1.2.0-hadoop2-bin.tar.gz and giraph-dist-1.2.0-bin.tar.gz.
Is there any documentation about that?

The only documentation that I found is the following one:

- Apache Hadoop 2 (latest version: 2.5.1)

  This is the latest version of Hadoop 2 (supporting YARN in addition
  to MapReduce) Giraph could use. You may tell maven to use this version
  with "mvn -Phadoop_2 ".

Comment: If I had to guess, one is built with Hadoop2 support. However, I don't think Giraph project is maintained anymore

Comment: Facebook still uses it and maintains it based on the commit history. https://github.com/apache/giraph/commits/trunk